# WindowsからLAN内のsamba(Ubuntu)にホスト名でアクセスしたい

Tags: linux, windows, network

Ubuntuにsambaをインストールしファイル共有を行っています。Ubuntuのホスト名はUBUNTU, sambaのコンフィグファイルに記入しているNetBIOS名も同じくUBUNTUです。
WindowsからUbuntuのローカルIPを使えば共有ファイルにアクセスできるのですが、ホスト名ではアクセスできません。
そもそも名前解決ができていないようです。`nslookup UBUNTU` に対して `Non-existent domain` が返ってきます。もちろんローカルIPアドレスに向けたpingは返ってきます。
LAN用のDNSサーバを立てなければいけないのでしょうか？追加のリソース無しでホスト名やNetBIOS名でアクセスできるようにしたいです。

[追記]
皆様ご回答ありがとうございます。

1. 現状は固定IPです
   そのためWindowsマシンのHostsに書き込むことが一番簡単ですね。ありがとうございます。
2. DHPCは自宅ルータが提供しています。
   Sambaサーバーを触るマシンが増えた場合にはSambaサーバーに`avahi-daemon`をインストールしDNSサーバの代わり？のような機能を利用するとよいということですね。
3. workgroupはWindowsマシンと同一のものに設定済みです。

追加の質問です。Windowsの場合にはDNSサーバーを立てずともLAN内の他のマシンのホスト名？NetBIOS名？が見えるのですが、このような機能は利用できないのでしょうか？

Comment: Ubuntu 側に割り当てられている IP アドレスは固定ですか？

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になりそうな感じです。[How to enable Samba connections via hostname](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-samba-connections-via-hostname/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。workgroup, NetBIOS名ともに設定済みです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 側が固定IPアドレスの場合、手っ取り早くは Windows 側の hosts ファイルに Samba (Ubuntu) の IP アドレスを記載してしまう方法が考えられます。
(ファイルの編集には管理者権限が必要)

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hsts**

```
192.168.1.xxx   UBUNTU
```

もしくは DHCP 環境の場合には、Ubuntu 側で avahi-daemon を動作させておくことで、IP アドレスの割当状況に関わらず (他のクライアントから) "サーバ名`.local`" の形式でアクセスすることが可能です。

```
$ sudo apt install avahi-daemon
$ sudo systemctl start avahi-daemon
$ sudo systemctl enable avahi-daemon
```

Answer (score 1):

WindowsとUbintuとでワークグループ名を一致させましょう。Windows側はシステムのプロパティ、Ubuntu側はsmb.confの`workgroup`行です。

---

`nslookup`はDNSによる名前解決を行うツールです。そのためDNS以外名前解決手段の結果（例えばhosts）が含まれることはありません。`ping`はOSによる名前解決を行うため、DNS以外の名前解決も使用されます。